# Why do I get "must be modifiable l-value" compiler error (C2105) on following code?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, iterator

I'm stumped by this one...the compiler outputs:

d:\data\personal\projects\test\test.cpp(42): error C2105: '--' needs l-value

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

class FOO
{
public:
    typedef int* iterator;
    typedef const int* const_iterator;

    class explicit_iterator : public std::iterator< std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, int >
    {
    public:
        explicit_iterator(int* ptr = nullptr) : m_ptr(ptr) {}
        bool operator ==(const explicit_iterator& rhs) const { return m_ptr == rhs.m_ptr; }
        bool operator !=(const explicit_iterator& rhs) const { return m_ptr != rhs.m_ptr; }

        reference operator *() const { return *m_ptr; }

        explicit_iterator& operator ++() { ++m_ptr; return *this; }
        explicit_iterator& operator --() { --m_ptr; return *this; }

    private:
        int* m_ptr;
    };

    FOO(int val = 0) { std::fill( begin(), end(), val ); }

    iterator begin() { return m_data; }
    iterator end() { return m_data + 10; }

    explicit_iterator begin2() { return explicit_iterator( begin() ); }
    explicit_iterator end2() { return explicit_iterator( end() ); }

private:
    int m_data[10];
};

int main (int, char *[])
{
    FOO foo;
    // This is the line that fails!  (Not this one, the one right below!!!)
    std::copy( foo.begin(), --foo.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, "\n" ) ); // C2105

    // All these variants are good
    std::copy( foo.begin2(), --foo.end2(), std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, "\n" ) ); // good
    std::copy( foo.begin(), foo.end() - 1, std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, "\n" ) ); // good
    int* end = foo.end();
    std::copy( foo.begin(), --end, std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, "\n" ) ); // good

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should use `std::prev(foo.end())`.

Comment: Without showing your line numbers, and just throwing error message and code without further notion it's pretty tedious to check what you have. @KerrekSB seems to have spotted it though ...

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Yes, seen that now. But he shouldn't have this comment letting scroll out. I'm trying to avoid at least horizontal scrollbars when I post code here ...

Comment: Edited for clarity (you guys are really picky)

Comment: @MarkB: Remember that *you* are the one that wants this question answered, others are helping you with *your* problem. Any help that you provide in identifying the issue is really for *your* benefit, not for *those picky guys*. In this case, the line was already marked, but the formatting of code moved the comment out of the visible space. Formatting the code so that it fits in the screen will help you and others in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot predecrement an rvalue or pointer type. The call `foo.end()` returns an rvalue `int*` and you cannot preincrement/predecrement that.

The next call works `--foo.end2()` as in this case the preincrement is a member function, and it is legal in the language to call a member function on an rvalue. The syntax is equivalent to the more explicit, which might make it simpler to understand:

```
foo.end2().operator--();
```

Comment: I can accept that "it's part of the language".  I'm still not sure *why* a compiler can't generate the right code.  If I wrote a templated PTR class that wrapped a pointer, I'd probably be able to make this code work.  Note: This is more of a curiosity...there are obvious many workarounds available...

Comment: @MarkB: *It's part of the language*. For fundamental types the behavior is inherited from C, and you are not allowed to *modify* an rvalue. You cannot assign, increment, decrement... the idea being that the operation is futile since the object won't outlive the expression. This is a conscious design choice, a different choice could have been made at language design time, but that ship sailed. Now for classes, it was considered important enough that member functions could be called on an rvalue, effectively breaking the choice of names lvalue/rvalue [...]

Comment: [...] which used to mean *can appear on the left/right side of an assignment expression*, but given that assignments are implemented as member functions, you can assign in C++ to an *rvalue*. But I am deviating. Yes, this *is* how the language goes, and that is probably the simple single answer.

Answer (score 0):

This statement is invalid.

std::copy( foo.begin(), --foo.end(), std::ostream_iterator( std::cout, "\n" ) ); // C2105

Function foo.end() returns a temporary object for which you may not apply operator --.

Answer (score 0):

The operand of pre-decrement must be a modifiable lvalue for built in types (like pointers). See C++11 5.3.2 "Increment and decrement".

The `FOO::end()` member function returns a built in type (pointer) that is an rvalue, not a modifiable lvalue, so the pre-decrement operator can't be used on it.

`FOO::end2()` returns an rvalue, but not of a built in type.  So the overloaded pre-decrement operator can be called.

And finally, `--end` is acting on a modifiable lvalue.